# Store DisplayChildren(model) in string variable for later modification

Tags: orchardcms

In Orchard i can see the menu is output in MenuItem.cshtml with the line DisplayChildren(model).

I would like to take this html output and run an xslt transform to change the structure.

How can i get the menu item as the html and store this in a local variable (as opposed to it being output directly to the stream)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var html = DisplayChildren(model);
```

Yup, it's that simple. It will give you a `IHtmlString`, that you can `ToString()` if you need to. But xslt? 8|

Comment: Wow thanks, ok time for me to download the source! Xslt because I need to write a custom menu as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099335/xslt-nested-menu-transform-based-on-featured-attribute/12103035#12103035

Comment: Wouldn't it be a million times easier to just override the templates?

Comment: @Bertland I dropped you a mail from the contact form on your blog! Cheers